# Error in vb.net ; Is there a way I can open a link using label / button?

Tags: vb.net, url, button, label

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim url As String = "www.google.com"
    Process.Start(url)
```

this code seems to show an error:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("www.google.com") { UseShellExecute = true});` -- You forgot to mention the UI Platform (assuming WinForms) and the .Net version (assuming .Net Core 3.1 / .Net 5).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to work?

> Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("www.google.com") { UseShellExecute
> = true}); -- You forgot to mention the UI Platform (assuming WinForms) and the .Net version (assuming .Net Core 3.1 / .Net 5). – Jimi 5 hours
> ago

Answer (score 0):

Try adding HTTP or HTTPS to the URL like this

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim url As String = "http://www.google.com"
    Process.Start(url)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm creating a PDF file using iText, and after I've got it saved on disk I do open it using this code:

```
        Process P = new Process();
        P.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\temp\\paquete.pdf";
        P.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        P.Start();
```

So, I think the main difference between your code and mine is what https://stackoverflow.com/users/14567563/skorture pointed out:

```
        P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
```

.NET Core is a bit different than .NET Framework Winforms.